# Wordpress Registration user role

Tags: wordpress, registration, user-roles

The default user role of my wordpress registration is a "subscriber". It is possible to create a Editor registration? or Author registration too?  any plugins can help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes There is a plugin where you can change the role and also you can

Block, Hide, Import, Export, everything in one plugin. Don't do in anything coding. **Just use the plugin and it's simple. **

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

Search this (User Role Editor) directly from your wordpress or click the above link.

If there is anything you can ask again. Thanks

Comment: i already have that plug-in but my problems is. How to have multiple registration for "subscriber" ,  "editor" and  "author" . btw thank you evrymuch for the answer

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-multiple-accounts/#installation

Note: Wordpress allow one user with one email but this plugin will work for you. If you said something like that......

Check this link and also below notes for this plugin installation

Go to the Users -> Multiple Accounts admin settings page (which you can also get to via the Settings link next to the plugin on the Manage Plugins page) and configure settings. On a Multisite install, go to My Sites -> Network Admin -> Users -> Multiple Accounts.